# Create SDL_Window unique_ptr

Tags: c++, sdl-2, unique-ptr

For my game I am trying to create an `SDL_GLContext` using `unique_ptr` with the help of `SDL_GL_CreateContext();`

I have created a custom deleter for my `unique_ptr`

```
struct sdl_deleter
{
    void operator()(SDL_Window *p) const { SDL_DestroyWindow(p); }
    void operator()(SDL_Renderer *p) const { SDL_DestroyRenderer(p); }
    void operator()(SDL_Texture *p) const { SDL_DestroyTexture(p); }
};

class MainGame{
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, sdl_deleter> _window;

public: 
    run();
}





MainGame::MainGame() : _window(nullptr, sdl_deleter), _screenWidth(1024), _screenHeight(768), _gameState(GameState::PLAY)
{

}

void MainGame::run(){
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
        _window.reset(SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, _screenWidth, _screenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL));
}
```

I get an error saying that the type is not allowed and i dont know how to come around it.

```
Error   C2664   'std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window,sdl_deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window,sdl_deleter> &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (__cdecl *)(SDL_Window *)' to 'const _Dx &'
```

The error is at the pointer initializer:

```
: _window(nullptr, sdl_deleter)
```

Comment: Hi I edit my question and realize I had problems with my initializer at the constructor but I don't understand why i am getting that error, i edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `_window(nullptr, sdl_deleter)` the `sdl_deleter` is a type name, while an object is expected. You should either provide an actual deleter object, e.g. `_window(nullptr, sdl_deleter{})` or simply leave it default-constructed by `unique_ptr` itself: `_window(nullptr)`.

Furthemore, `SDL_GL_CreateContext` expects an `SDL_Window *`, while you are feeding it with `unique_ptr`. You probably want this: `SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window.get())`.